# Select option right-border missing on firefox

Tags: css, firefox, select

I'm having trouble with the render of the dropdown menu of a select element on firefox. Depending on the width of the select, the right border of the option elements is sometimes missing. The issue can be seen here on most of the select dropdowns: http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/select-single-option/

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOfI7.jpg

How can I fix the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: we need to see the code !

Comment: I'm using yahoo purecss forms (http://purecss.io/forms/). You can see the issue on their forms demo page as well (the first select in the stacked form section).